# Knockout html binding not working (bound to a function calling a partial view) in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I have an ASP .NET MVC application, additonally I am using Knockout 2.0.0. I created a partial view which I would like to render to the page using knockout. The partial needs to be rendered within a Knockout foreach statement. I am unable to get the knockout HTML binding to work, and so I'm currently using a hack to put the html into the div using JQuery.

There is a lot of html on this page, so it's not possible to post all of the source code, so I will try and post the pertinent code:

```
<div data-bind="foreach:issues">
    @* SNIP - A lot of other html here*@
    <div id="myPartialDiv" data-bind="html: $parent.getHtml(issueId())">
    </div>  
</div>
```

Further down I have the following javascript function on my KO View Model (I have commented out my hack and included the code that returns HTML):

```
   var getHtml = function (issueId) {
              var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("GetHtmlAction","MyController")';
              $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: baseUrl,
                    data: "&issueId=" + issueId,
                    success: function (data) {
                        //$('#mypartialDiv').html(data);                          
                        return data;
                    },
                    error: function (req, status, error) {
                        //$('#myPartialDiv').html('Something went wrong.');
                        return 'Something went wrong.'
                    },
                    dataType: "text"
                });
         }
```

The code above results in no data being rendered to the page. USing Chrome debug tools, I see that there are no javascript errors occuring, and knockout is simply not binding the html of the div to the results returned from the getHtml function.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you applying the bindings? Your example retrieves the data, but does nothing with it, as far as I can see.

Comment: Yeah, sorry that code is not included but I am calling ko.applyBindings() on the page, and other bindings on the page work.

Comment: Oh and the function is being called when the HTML binding occurs, but it seems that knockout does not use the results (the 'return data;' line). If I remove my comments above the update is successful (using JQuery to update the div.Html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Miroslav Popovic explains, the problem is that the AJAX request is asynchronous, so the `return data` is ignored and there is no return value from your call to `getHtml`.

I would suggest using a custom binding that handles the asynchronous HTML loading (I've put a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9CkHd/)).

This works by taking 2 parameters to the asyncHtml: a function to call that takes a success callback as it's final parameter (plus any other parameters) and an array of the parameters that need to be passed to that function.

```
<div id="myPartialDiv" data-bind="asyncHtml: { source: getHtml, params: [123] }">Loading...</div>
```

The custom binding then grabs these values, concats a custom callback onto the parameters that are passed to it, and calls the specified function:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.asyncHtml = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var parameters = value.params.concat([function(data) {
           $(element).html(data); 
        }]);
        value.source.apply(null, parameters);
    }
};
```

Finally we can re-implement our view model HTML-retrieving method to make the POST call and invoke the new success handler:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.getHtml = function(issueId, callback) {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/echo/html/",
                data: {
                        html: "<p>server response " + issueId + "</p>",
                        delay: 1
                    },
                success: callback,
                dataType: "text"
            });            
    };
};
```

Note: for this example I am using the jsFiddle `echo` to post back a random response

Comment: I have now made this answer into a blog post as it seemed like a reusable implementation: http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2012/06/12/loading-mvc-partialviews-asynchronously-using-knockoutjs/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I will mark this as the correct answer as it provides a working example. I am unable to vote up your answer as I don't have enough reputation. I have not yet implemented this, but it looks like exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`$.ajax` is an asynchronous call. When you call it, the execution will just continue to the next statement in the `getHtml` function. Since this is the last statement, the `getHtml` function will return `undefined`.

About your `return data;`... This return is within a success callback function. The data will be result of **that** function, not the parent `getHtml` function. Besides, `getHtml` is already completed. You can't return a result from it.

How about having an observable property in your view model called `html`, and then find some other means of triggering the `getHtml` function (button click, some other success callback, issueId property change...), that will in turn set the 'html' property value. Then you could simply data-bind to that property `data-bind="html: html"`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, this makes perfect sense. I would like to vote up your response but I don't yet have enough reputation. I'd prefer to Steve Greatrex's answer as correct since it provides an implementation that I can use. But thanks very must for your response.

Comment: Not a problem. Steve's solution is great. +1